# How to solve problem with Two Date Fields and multiple cases

Tags: date-range, mysql-5.6

I have two tables

```
(CREATE TABLE ta_product_discount_details(
  RowID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  DiscountID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  SKU varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  FromDate date DEFAULT NULL,
  ToDate date DEFAULT NULL,
  Price double DEFAULT,
  Timestamp timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (RowID)
)
```

and
anotheer temp table with the same structure that i use as a temp table to insert new rows.

Now, my problem is this:

For example:
In main list i have Product1 with Discount Price that goes active between two dates (FromDate, ToDate). Everything is OK by far.
But, when i create another list with the same product but different dates, i want do "disable" the first product but the problem is when i start checking dates which one is bigger so price from that list is Enabled. It is hard to explain everything because we could have multiple cases:

Example

What if the first list is like this

FromDate: 02/14/2020, ToDate: 06/24/2020.

And then the second list is created like this -

FromDate: 02/16/2020, ToDate: 06/30/2020.....

and much more cases like this one.

Please help if someone knows what shoul i do.
By the way, i am using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: All you do is `select Price WHERE NOW() BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: He is also doing the `broken enter key`... (sigh) , and not back-reading his own question for typing errors....

Comment: @Luuk English is not my language and of course i make mistakes in writing. So thank for you comment. I just asked for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the trigger which will disable the previous product on insert of new one of same product but for that you might have to add another column to know which one is enabled or disabled.

Comment: That would mean you could not pre-load the discounts. Not very user friendly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but when i insert new product i want to “disable” previous prices. And oh, i forgot to mention that also i need to update prices for each marketplace. So, if the list is created for Amazon DE, and the second list is for Amazon DE also, than update only the prices that belongs to the list of marketplace.